# Django/Angular 4 CORS issue

Tags: django, cross-domain, x-frame-options, django-cors-headers

I am running *two angular 4 apps* served through **two django different apps** (as static files served. That is working perfectly fine). I have a **"parent app"** and a **"child app"**.

Both apps are served through their own Django application on their own identical app ( we literally copied the django app to serve both the parent and the child). ]

**THE ISSUE:** We are facing a CORS issue between loading the child app on the parent app in an iFrame.

**what's going on:**
The *chld app* is *loaded* by the *parent appp*

**Parent app:**

```
<div *ngIf="theRoute">
   <iframe [src]="myUrl" appHeght id="myIFrame"></iframe>
</div>
```

**My parent-app IFrame Component:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    // The Router is correct, and so are the params. 
    this.myRouter = this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        ...
        this.myUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://127.0.0.1:8201/'); // location of the child
       ... // more stuff, including change detection

      }
    );
  }
```

my **PARENT DJANGO App - SETTINGS.PY:**

```
import os
import datetime

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'my parent secret'

DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = '*'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'spa.middleware.SPAMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_project_proj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_project_proj.wsgi.application'


# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'  #'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = './frontend/dist/parent-app'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8201',
    'http://localhost:8201'
)
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW'
```

*I've also allowed X_FRAME-OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM http://localhost:8201* --> this is the location of the parent component. I have allowed both localhost:8200 and 127.0.0.1/8201. Both gave the same error.

**AND THIS IS MY CHILD DJANGO APP SETTINGS:**

```
import os
import datetime
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'my child secret'

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = '*'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'spa.middleware.SPAMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_child.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_child.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'  #'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = './frontend/dist/child-one-app'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8201',
    'http://localhost:8201'
)
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW'
```

As you can see, both my child and my parent component allow CORS. But for some reason, I'm still getting this error in my IFrame:

> Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8201/': 'ALLOW' is not a recognized directive. The
>   header will be ignored.

**AND this error: **

> ERROR DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

***My overall question:*** so even though I've enabled CORS in both my parent and child app, why is my child app still giving me a CORS issue?. I've tried everything to access this cross origin including doing a `iframeID.contentWindow.postMessage() and in my *child app* make a window.addEventListener('message', myRecever, false). the reciver App in my *child app* did nothing but *call itself* over and over again!!

**my child component receive method:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoaderService } from './services/loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private loaderService: LoaderService = LoaderService.getInstance();
  constructor() {
    window.addEventListener('message', this.receiveMessage, false);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService.removeSpinner();
  }

  private receiveMessage(event) {
    console.log("event origin:" , event.origin);

    event.source.postMessage('verified', event.origin);
  }
}
```

That console.log event keeps calling itself in my iFrame and my child component over and over again! Why?!

Comment: *“Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'http://127.0.0.1:8201/': 'ALLOW' is not a recognized directive.”* — The X-Frame-Options header value needs to have `allow-from`, not `allow`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Syntax

Comment: I've tried both. I get the same error regardless :(

Comment: If after changing the X-Frame-Options header value to have `allow-from`, you are still getting a message saying `'ALLOW' is not a recognized directive`, then that either means your browser is reloading a stale response from its cache, or else your server is sending multiple `X-Frame-Options` headers. Rtegardless, it’s not a CORS issue. It’s a different type of cross-domain issue